# Not able to get cookie from microsoft.sharepoint.com site on Task scheduler

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have create one poc console application to get cookie from site "https Microsoft.SharePoint.com"

InternetGetCookieEx of wininet.dll

to authenticate and access SharePoint site files.  when I click that Application exe, it is successfully fetching cookie from this site. but when I schedule in Windows Task Scheduler. it is not fetching Cookie.

Same thing is working with Task scheduler also in some other server.

Please help me if I have to change some setting for it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it an HTTP only cookie?

Comment: Hi Jan, I don't know really, but I trying to get cookie from https url.